# How can I avoid mutation prop and modify the same in other component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I'm a new Dev VUE.JS and reading a lot too about "share/pass" data to anothers components, but I'm not getting perceive this examples useful in my component.

```
Table.vue - Fetch API and populate a table.
File.vue -  Instance Table.vue and here I'm trying to override the component variable.
```

Table:

```
<template>
    <v-simple-table class="mt-5" id="tableOs" dense >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th v-for="h in headers" v-bind:key="h.value">{{h.text}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>      
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.customer}}</td>
            <td>{{item.neighbor}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </v-simple-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data (){
      return{
        headers: [
          { text: 'Id', value: 'id' },
          { text: 'Name', value: 'customer' },
          { text: 'Neighbor', value: 'neighbor' }
        ],
        items: this.pitems,    
      }
    },
    props:{
      'pitems': []
    },
    async created(){      
        const res = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:5000/buscarx/3",
            {
              method:"GET"
            }
        );
        const data = await res.json()
        this.items = data
    }
}  
</script>
```

and my Files.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container
    id="dashboard"
    fluid
    tag="section"
  >
    <v-btn @click="modify()"> </btn>
    <TableOS />
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
    components:{
      Table: () => import('./components/Table')
    },
    methods:{
      modify(){
        console.log(this.item)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Anyone can me help, suggest the best way to use this fetch and modify the data in the table to use a Filter for example in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) to pass variables from one component to another.
For example, you need to fetch your items data in the `created` hook inside File.vue. Save the fetched items in `items` array.
Then, you can pass this `items` array via `prop` to the Table.vue component.

You can modify, filter, map and perform other tasks to the `items` array in the File.vue. The changes will be reactive and automatically reflect in the Table.vue file.

You can also share variables between components using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). But, in case of variable sharing between child and parent, like in your case, you don't need this. But if the relation between components is not so simple or they are not related you have to use `vuex`.